# Why is the ~ selector not working here?

Tags: html, css

In the navigation menu, I have a bottom border that applies to the selected section and the hover action..

```
 <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#" id="selected">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

css:

```
 nav a:hover, #selected {
 border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
 }
```

What I want is the border to vanish from the #selected id when I hover over another list item..
I tried something like..

```
 nav a:hover ~ #selected {
 border-bottom: none;
 }
```

But that doesn't work, wherever I put the #selected. and even with + selector instead.

maybe even better if it's possible to make the bottom border move in x-index to the hovered item..

Comment: Is it right that you want `#selected` to have a border by default?

Answer (score 3):

`~` doesn't extend to "*cousins*" like the `<a>` elements. It's only for direct siblings like the `<li>`s.

```css
nav li:hover ~ li #selected {
    /* */
}
```

And, even then, it's only for siblings that follow. So, it can find `About` from `Home`, but not the other way around.

Though, you may be able to react to the `<nav>` or `<ul>` being hovered over:

```css
nav a:hover,
#selected,
nav:hover #selected:hover /* override next selector and rule */ {
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
}

nav:hover #selected {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Eh8M/

Comment: Unfortunately your new rule is more specific than the original rule adding the border.  As a result this will remove the border from the `#selected` element even when hovering over that element itself.  You would need to amend the original selector to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You were targeting the `a` elements, which aren't siblings, rather they are children of the sibling `li` elements.

---

Aside from that, the sibling selector `~` doesn't select elements preceding it, just elements succeeding it.

Thus, since `#selected` is the first child of the `ul`, it isn't selected. On the contrary, had `#selected` been the last element, it would work *in theory*; however, that doesn't solve your problem.

To achieve the desired results, you could remove the `border-bottom` when hovering over the `ul`.

```
ul:hover #selected {
    border-bottom:none;
}
#selected, a#selected:hover, a:hover {
    border-bottom:10px solid pink;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dUWU9/) - this appears to be what you want - `10px` added for visibility purposes.

Comment: `#selected` is the`a` and not a child of the `ul`; it has no sblings anyways. James is right in this.

Answer (score 1):

Each `a` is within its own `li`.  Therefore, `#selected` has no siblings that match `a`.  Siblings share the same direct parent.  Your anchors do not.

Comment: what would be the recommended fix, then? ;-)

Comment: Why on earth was this, a correct (if, and only *arguably*, incomplete) answer down-voted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual fix which works for me:

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg7y8/2/)

```
/* #selectd has a border by default */
li #selected {
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
}
/* but not link (not even #selected) does have a border on hovering */
ul:hover a, ul:hover a#selected {
    border: none;
}
/* all hovered links should have a border (incl. #selected) */
ul a:hover, ul a#selected:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
}
```

Unfortunately, moving the cursor into the rectangle of `ul` also triggers the border's removal of `#selected`. Using JavaScript would then be an easier (not to say the only) solution which could fix this issue.